# 30A device with 20A plug...whaaa?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I purchased an [automotive lift](https://www.atlasautoequipment.com/products/lifts/four-post-lifts/hobbyist-4-post-lifts/garage-pro-8000-ext). It requires 120v / 30A...BUT comes with a standard household style plug (NEMA 5-15P) on the cord. Under the specifications tab on the website it states: "110 Volt, 30 AMP BREAKER REQUIRED".

I tried it on a standard 20A circuit and it occasionally will trip the breaker so I have to believe that it does in fact require 30A.

Before I reach out to Atlas I want to be sure first that this is a violation.

Comment: Usually a maker can use smaller than recommended wires/plugs and should be okay if the device is UL tested.  Is there a UL(or similar) symbol/logo on the device/packaging?  It does seem odd because I doubt you can put in 5-15 receptacle on a 30 amp circuit legally.

Comment: Actually it is worse than "30A with 20A". This is "30A with 15A". 20A (5-20) receptacles are very common in commercial buildings, less common in residential. So the vast majority of ordinary consumer electrical appliances (space heaters, vacuum cleaners, etc.) are designed specifically to match a 15A circuit - i.e., 1,500W continuous (e.g., space heaters) or 1,875W non-continuous (e.g., hair dryers). But if something requires a lot more than that, it should come with a different plug. In addition, "110V" is an indication that they are way behind *or* are not really getting things approved

Comment: properly (UL, ETL, etc.). The standard has been 120V for many years, and 125V is used in many respects (125V x 12A = 1,500W, 125V x 15A = 1,875W). Which makes me think they're slapping together motors and stuff without bothering with UL or ETL (which cost a lot to test/certify and for a product that isn't really designed for ordinary household use, I can see why they would do that) - but still they should ship it with no plug or with a plug that matches their stated specs (30A).

Comment: What country are you in? The directions state "Make sure to install a proper circuit breaker on the circuit (**DZ47-63/ D32A/2P** is suggested for single phase 110V);". That doesn't seem to be an American circuit breaker. Maybe they're relying on the fact that wire overload is calculated by time spent using excess amperage? If you do end up going with a 20amp receptacle then at least make sure that the wire from the circuit breaker is at least 10AWG on a 30amp breaker. It seems like they gave you the wrong plug so maybe you're supposed to splice in your own or hardwire it?

Comment: The fact that it specs a 110v outlet is sketchy. It reflects a poor understanding of modern electrical systems in general.

Comment: As the comments and answers seem to indicate the plug choice is iffy at best, just wondering if standing below 4 tons is a good idea.

Comment: Reach out to Atlas for what?  What are you hoping they would do?

Comment: Note that, from a purely physics point of view, the problem is heat buildup, which is a function of power draw over time.  So if it only occasionally draws up to 30A very briefly, and 15 or less the rest of the time then you're not looking at too serious of a hazard.  For a car lift that (presumably) you're not going to run up and down under full load repeatedly just for fun it's probably not *too* likely to melt the plug.  On the other hand, breakers can only be tripped so many times before they wear out, so a 30A plug and a 30A circuit would definitely be better.

Comment: @Perkins and if you did run it continuously you'd probably pop the motor overload (thermal) trip before the wires reached a dangerous temperature.  Putting the overload trip on the motor makes A LOT of sense, since it can directly observe motor temperature, which is the thing we care most about.

Answer (score 16):

### That company looks a little bit sketch.

"Atlas automotive lifts" has a generic/nonsense-word "About Me" page which says nothing.  However, they are a brand of ISN, which operates a huge **warehouse** on the east side of Indianapolis.  I've been within a half mile of the place.  It's definitely a warehouse and not a factory, because ISN's website graciously shows us photos of the building interior, and giving their best effort to sell themselves as an American provider, they show us stacks of pallets and not fabrication jigs.  Sat photos show us a building with far too few trucks docked to possibly be intaking large amounts of raw materials.

So this stuff is being built "in unspecified locations", *you know what I mean*.

But the building has their name on it, and hopefully they have enough assets in the US to avoid any temptation of selling *absolute swill*.  However, given their variety of products and low volume on each, I don't gather any of it has seen the inside of a UL testing lab.  I'd be happy to be wrong.

But without UL supervision, they are going to most likely install the plug their customers expect -- the NEMA 5-15 "15A" plug.  UL would have told them to install the 5-20 which would not have bothered commercial customers at all, but would cause customer support issues with residential customers.

How to interpret this wrinkle? I honestly do not know.  If I was buying a car lift, I would hope that company has a Safety Team skilled on mechanical things; I wouldn't be overly concerned if the team was not fully up to speed on some obscure article in the *electrical* code.

Speaking of which...

### Motors are *weird*

The article on motors, article 430, is practically its own electrical code. It's huge.  But to try to crack it down to something simple, **Most large motors have *internal* overload protection**, which relieves the need of the branch circuit breaker to perform that function.

The only remaining breaker functions we need are short-circuit (hot-neutral) and bolted ground fault (hot-ground) protection, and that is a magnetic/instant trip for which matching exact breaker size is not essential.

So, a 30A breaker on a 20A circuit sounds legit when the load is **one single motor load**, unless the motor or equipment labeling or instructions says otherwise.

### Of course, this means a *dedicated circuit*

Because such a wackadoodle 30A breaker/20A wire/20A socket arrangement *is only legal for this piece of equipment* (and other motor loads with similar issues).

I would argue since you're running the wire *anyway*, why not run **a more usable wire that will raise your resale value**. Noting that people whose homes already have decent size 240V sockets are getting significantly higher offers, because the buyers figure the home is EV-ready.

Comment: The manual indicates to direct wire it. I'm betting the importer installs the cord to avoid getting calls about 'this thing can't plug in!' from buyers.

Comment: _"If I was buying a car lift, I would hope that company has a Safety Team skilled on mechanical things"_ You want that lift to be ALI Certified (www.autolift.org), and it appears Atlas' lifts are, though with anything I'd be careful of "fine print" and would want to make certain any given lift is actually certified.  I can fix a sketchy 110v plug; not having a hoist drop a car on me is a different matter.

Comment: _"Most large motors have internal overload protection, which relieves the need of the branch circuit breaker to perform that function."_ I am not clear on how the need is relieved. Is it not possible, for example, for equipment to be damaged in a way that creates a near-short? If that were, say, 4.5 Ω it would draw 28 A continuous through wires rated for 20 A, without tripping the 30 A circuit breaker, which seems unsafe.

Comment: "since you're running the wire anyway, why not run a more usable wire that will raise your resale value. Noting that people whose homes already have decent size 240V sockets are getting significantly higher offers, because the buyers figure the home is EV-ready." do you have a source for this?  I'm skeptical that someone is going to pay **significantly** more b/c EV ready. Electricians exist to make any house EV ready.  I agree that if you're going to run a wire, upsizing is good b/c incremental cost of bigger wire is small relative to overall cost.

Comment: The second-most pressing question (after the general quality of the lift) I would have is a practical one: Is it reasonably safe to rely on the 20A circuit breaker to protect me from basically an electric fire caused by pulling too many amps through too thin a wire? That is, apart from code etc: Can the OP continue to run the lift on that outlet or is he in danger of burning down his house?

Comment: @cjs I don't sit on the NEC code-writing committee that writes Article 430, but I presume it's because a wire short that draws *only so few amps* is highly improbable.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Because "a higher offer" folds into the mortgage at negligible additional cost.  Whereas electricians want cash.  Consider also the uncertainty of needing a service upgrade, which is all but a certainty when someone asks for a 50-60A outlet unawares that a 15-20A outlet will satisfy their needs.

Comment: @Peter since motor rules typically permit a 30A breaker on #12 wire on that type of setup, I can't see how substituting a 20A breaker would be any worse.  Mind you, the circuit needs to be dedicated to that motor load.

Answer (score 6):

Most electricians just from details in the question will probably suspect this is not a product approved or designed for use in North America.

Generally this on this site most questions are US, and the NEMA plug seems to confirm that this question is too, so the Code that applies is probably the NEC.

The NEC right at the beginning of the book requires that products be tested and listed by recognized testing lab, and installed and used only as indicated in the included instructions. Those instructions supersede the provisions that follow in the Code.

I downloaded the instructions to verify the exact wording and to look for other missed details. The first thing that really stands out is no reference to UL, CSA, ETL or other testing lab approval. I don't recall ever seeing a product that didn't have that included in the instructions. You might want to take a look for a label on the equipment to see if it is marked such. (You might find a mark on the motor, that doesn't count). A symbol indicating "[CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking)" is a no-go, CE is mark self certifying that it was built to a set of EU standards, and is not a qualifying testing mark.

If you don't find a lab mark it's probably a waste of time to call a factory rep except to ask the longshot question of if they sent the wrong instructions and have a different set of instructions for the US market.

To get close to NEC installation you would likely need #10 wire and a 30A receptacle/plug, but there are NEC provisions (240.4(G)/422/430) where #12 wire with insulation better than NM/Romex might work depending on exact motor amperage if hard wired with an appropriate disconnect within site.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a violation? Almost certainly yes.
As far as I'm aware there's no code-compliant way to use a 15A receptacle on a 30A circuit.
There's also no code-compliant way to put a 30A breaker on a circuit which uses #12 or smaller wires (which your existing circuit uses since it's a 20A circuit).

The only way to run this machine safely in a somewhat code-complaint way would be to run a new 30A circuit from your electrical panel using #10 or larger wire, and to use a 5-30R, L5-30R or TT-30 receptacle.
You'd also need to change the plug on it to match the 30A receptacle you use, and since you're doing that it would probably be well worthwhile to replace the entire cord to the device with one that you know is rated for 30A (#10 or larger), since if this manufacturer put a 15 plug on the end I doubt they used the appropriate wire gauge in the cord.

I write "*somewhat* code complaint" above because the modifications you'd need to make to the machine would mean that you'd not be using it according to the manufacturer's instructions (even though those instructions are unsafe).

Comment: I would consider hardwiring the lift rather than using a plug at all. That takes out a point of failure / some cost and skips the whole question of what plug to use.